# Mean Squared Error on test set: 68096390554.55103 and after optimization is Mean squared error: 38132179764.06082. What can I do to make it better?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to build a Gradient boosting regressor for predicting the emissions from ships on ports. I am getting terrible results. The paramters I have are :
Motor_Ship  Type_of_Load    Docking_Day Docking_Time    Sailing_Day Departure_Time  Permanence  Motor_Ship  Year_of_Construct   IMO Max_Speed   Avg_Speed   Gross_tonnage   Dead_Weight EM_Fuel AE_Fuel Engine_Speed    Power_ME    LF_ME_Cruising  A_ME    Power_AE    LF_ME_Maniobra  T_min_Hotell_Formato    T_min_Hotell    Energy_ME_Cruising  Energy_ME_Maniobra  Energy_AE_Cruising  Energy_AE_Maniobra  Energy_AE_Hotelling ME_Cruising ME_Maniobra AE_Cruising AE_Maniobra AE_Hotelling    Caldera_Maniobra    Caldera_Hotelling   Subtotal_NoCald Total

Where Total is the total emissions.

```
`# Separate features and target variable
X = df[['Motor_Ship','Type_of_Load','Year_of_Construct','Max_Speed','Avg_Speed','Gross_tonnage','Dead_Weight','EM_Fuel','AE_Fuel','Engine_Speed','A_ME']]
y = df['Total']

# Split data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Train Gradient Boosting model
gb_model = GradientBoostingRegressor(loss='squared_error', learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=100, max_depth=3, random_state=42)
gb_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Evaluate model on test set
y_pred = gb_model.predict(X_test)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
print("Mean Squared Error on test set: ", mse)`
```

I also encoded the columns with no numerical values and I added mean values to the columns with missing values.The mean square error I am getting is not improving even after optimization. Can someone tell me what I should do to get better results.

```
`model = GradientBoostingRegressor()

# define hyperparameters for optimization
param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [100, 500, 1000],
    'learning_rate': [0.1, 0.05, 0.01],
    'max_depth': [3, 5, 7],
    'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10],
    'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4],
    'max_features': [None, 'sqrt']
}

# create GridSearchCV object to optimize hyperparameters
grid_search = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=model,
    param_grid=param_grid,
    cv=5,
    scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
    n_jobs=-1
)

# fit GridSearchCV object to training data
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predict on test data with optimized model
y_pred = grid_search.predict(X_test)

# calculate mean squared error of predictions
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
print("Mean squared error: ", mse)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this problem is Gradient Exploding, which means that greater layers, larger value of the weight or Gradient Vanishing, which means that greater layers, smaller value of the weight. (it depends on your data when you don't have normalization.)

There are two possible solutions.

First of all, you can add normalization. This can prevent your data from increasing significantly to the range where you don't wanna expect.

This is `min-max scalar normalization`. Here is a [reference](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/normalization-vs-standardization), and this is an official [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) from sklearn.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler().fit(X_test)
X_norm = min_max_scaler.transform(X)
```

Second, decrease the number of `max_depth`. But, it might be limited to the performance of your model. So it is better to choose the first option.